# How to translate: 我发音得不太准

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

我发音得不太准.

- Does it translate as "My pronunciation is the best/exact?"

What is the meaning of 准? Does it depends on the context?

Comment: 准 means accurate / standard. 不太准 means `not so standard` and your translation means right the opposite...

Comment: if you add 地干活 to the end of your sentence，我地发音得不太准的干活。voila,, it would be a Japanese-Chinese sentence，so called 洋泾浜话。Anyway,you should avoid that serious mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`准` has a lot of meanings according to the context. Usually it means `accurate(准确)` but in this case it's `标准`, which means `standard`.

BTW, I think you may want to say `我发音发得不太准` / `我的发音不太准` rather than `我发音得不太准`.

Answer (score 2):

我发音得不太准 - My pronunciation is not very accurate.

准 usually means "standard", but in this context it means accurate/correct.

Answer (score 2):

我 发  音  不太准.
S  V   O   adverb  
“得” is not necessary

"My pronunciation is not very accurate." 
or 
“I can not pronounce accurately/well”。
ps.
的： adjective noun    美丽的花园
地： adjective（adverb） verb    大声地唱歌
得： verb adverb    吃得很饱

Answer (score 1):

Fyi, another way to translate the English is "我音发得不太准", where you swap the verb and the object so that the verb can be modified by the adverbial phrase that attaches to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just say "I have accent"?